# Set background color on Visual Studio Code Markdown Preview

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I'm currently using the default `Dark+` color theme on Visual Studio Code and the markdown preview is using the same style (black background color and white text).

How can I change to a light theme just for the markdown preview, like dark text and white background? I've tried writing something like `"markdown.preview.background": "#FFFFFF"` in the `settings.json` file without success.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you have either to write your own extension, or use something like this:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.markdown-preview-github-styles

Comment: the point is it seems possible watching vscode markdown page https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/languages/Markdown/md-dynamic-preview.gif

Comment: related feature-request: [Preview Themes (Markdown Preview Themes) #163020](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/163020)

Answer (score 22):

On the [Visual Studio Code markdown documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown) they have actually used the extension [**Markdown Preview Github Styling**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.markdown-preview-github-styles)

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked. Once installed, you search for `markdown-preview-github-styles.colorTheme` in settings and can choose your light or dark preferences.

Answer (score 17):

A simple way to achieve this other than creating your own stylesheet for each project, is by installing the [Markdown Preview Enhanced](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced) extension. The default markdown theme for the extension is white, but you can also choose a different them by setting the "markdown-preview-enhanced.previewTheme" in settings.json

```
"markdown-preview-enhanced.previewTheme": "medium.css"
```

A full list of available themes will be displayed as you start typing in the json value.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking to switch from light to dark and there's a setting for that in the extension. My eyes are saved.

Answer (score 16):

With the `Markdown Preview Enhanced` extension you can choose your theme now in either the GUI or `settings.json`. Time of writing 2021-04-08

```json
"markdown-preview-enhanced.previewTheme": "github-dark.css"
```

[image: Markdown Preview Enhanced Dark Theme]

Comment: This is NOT built in functionality.. You have to install a plugin in order to get it working!

Comment: Sorry I should have specified built-in to Markdown Preview Enhanced extension.

Comment: Did they remove this setting? I can't find it in the Command Palette and can't set it.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and could not find an out-of-the-box solution to fix it. So I went ahead and made a modified version of the default `markdown.css` to work for the Dark+ theme: https://github.com/dhdhagar/vscode-md-preview-light.

In VSCode, just edit the **Markdown: Styles** configuration or add the following line to `settings.json`:

```
"markdown.styles": [
        "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/dhdhagar/vscode-md-preview-light/style.min.css"
    ]
```

Answer (score 8):

One way to get white background color in markdown preview while having a dark VS Code theme is to use the [**Markdown Preview GitHub Styling**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.markdown-preview-github-styles) VS Code extension by *Matt Bierner*.

As the Markdown Preview GitHub Styling *by default selects the theme type (light vs dark) based on your VS Code theme*, you need to set

```
    "markdown-preview-github-styles.colorTheme": "light",
```

In your `settings.json`. (`Ctrl-Shift-P` -> `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`).

#### Using VS Code on WSL or Remote session?

- Then, you'll have to install the *Markdown Preview GitHub Styling* extension *in the WSL / Remote machine*, and edit the **Remote** Settings `settings.json`: (`Ctrl-Shift-P` -> `Preferences: Open Remote Settings (JSON) (RemoteName)`)

Answer (score 5):

1. Create *styles.css* file in root of your directory/workspace.
2. Add `markdown.styles: ["styles.css"]` in settings.json
3. In *styles.css*, add `body { background: #fff; }`

To achieve the same thing without all this hassle, you could also do this:

```
<body style="background: #fff;">
// Your markdown code
</body>
```

Comment: In settings.json

Comment: Note that, by using a css file, VS Code doesn't update preview panel instantly to reflect changes. Background style seems to be reflected in preview panel upon opening only.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question while trying to render only parts of the document in white background. This is how you do it without messing the settings file.

```
my text in default styling

<div style="background: #FFFFFF; color: #000">
my text in black with white background
</div>

my text back in default styling
```

[image]

PS: You can this trick to render LaTeX equations for screenshotting to other editors.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this extension called [Markdown Live](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=keshan.markdown-live) which helps to preview markdown and it comes with a WYSIWG editor which will help to easily edit any markdown content. It also  provides following features

- Renders multiple .md files
- Instantly sync changes from WYSIWG editor into text document and vice-versa
- Supports vscode themes

Answer (score 0):

This guide for VScode Office Viewer(Markdown Editor) extension.
The task is to make markdown background light and independent from VScode color theme.

1. in vscode click F1, write "open settings (JSON)"
2. in settings.json add this line: "vscode-office.autoTheme": false,
3. reload vscode

Answer (score -1):

It was solved for me by changing  the "editor.renderWhitespace": "none" property to *true*, in *settings.json* file:

```
{
    "editor.renderWhitespace": true
}
```