# How to use light-css when writing markdown in vscode when the theme is dark mode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, markdown

This is the markdown preivew in default mode
[markdown preview in darkmode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyYM8.png)
But I prefer the preview in this color mode`"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light"`
[markdown preview in Visual Studio Light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek8ro.png)
I know that the css files are placed in `"...\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\markdown-language-features\media\markdown.css"`, but I don't know much about CSS, and when I just copy the parameters from `light` to `dark`, it doesn't perform well.
Is it possible to preview light-css in dark mode with just a little modification?

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for a light-themed stylesheet for markdown preview to use with a VScode dark theme ?

In VSCode, edit the Markdown: Styles configuration or add the following line to settings.json:

```json
"markdown.styles": [
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/dhdhagar/vscode-md-preview-light/style.min.css"
]
```

This should do the trick. Also, if your using a theme like 'One Dark Pro', You must also turn off it's markdown style in config.json.

Comment: you ripped this off from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63086421/11107541 didn't you?